# Tengo un problema con ECHO JSON_ENCODE

Tags: php

Estoy teniendo el siguiente problema con echo json_encode y una funcion en mi curso de Udemy. Ya lei una consulta parecida, pero no me sirvio y el problema no es el mismo. Me pasa lo siguiente:

1- La funcion "obtenerServicios" se resalta con un error (`'obtenerServicios': not all code paths return a valuePHP(PHP0405)`) cuando le agrego ": array" y al final un "return $servicios". (No sé por qué al inyectar codigo quedan por fuera la funcion "obtenerServicios" y la llamad aa la funcion al final del codigo).

```
function obtenerServicios() : array {
    try {
        
        // importar conexion
        require 'database.php';

        // Escribir el codigo SQL
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM servicios;";
        $consulta = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

        // Arreglo vacio
        $servicios = [];
        $i = 0;

        // Obtener resultados
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta) ) {

            $servicios[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
            $servicios[$i]['nombre'] = $row['nombre'];
            $servicios[$i]['precio'] = $row['precio'];

            $i++;    
        }

        return $servicios; 

    }   catch (\Throwable $th) {
        //throw $th;

        var_dump($th);
    }
}

obtenerServicios();
```

Lo siguiente que tengo en el archivo "servicios.php" es esto:

[image: something]

Aca deberia funcionar todo con un `echo json_encode($servicios);` en lugar de un var_dump. Con el var_dump se muestra el resultado como arrays. Pero al utilizar el echo json_encode, se deja de mostrar los datos de la base de datos.

Esto hace que en localhost:85/appsalon no se muestren los servicios como deberia ser. No se si fui muy claro. No logro encontrar que es lo que falla. El profesor tiene todo tal cual esta en las imagenes y no tuvo problema, Por ultimo adjunto lo que hay en el archivo "app.js" y un error en la consola. Esto continua iterando en los datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El catch está entregando algo que no incluye un return (está imprimiendo en la salida estándar, pero no retorna nada a quien lo invocó). Te está diciendo que no todos los caminos posibles en tu método tienen un return

Comment: Es como dice @Alfabravo, quizá al profesor le funciona porque no se levanta Exception en su caso. Prueba a cambiar `var_dump($th);` por **`return array('error'=>$th->getMessage());`** El `var_dump` estaría rompiendo el tipo de dato esperado, que es un array, en caso de error.

Comment: si alguna de las respuesta que te dieron responde tu duda recuerda marcarla como respondida/resuelta.

Answer (score 0):

pon esto en el catch:

```
}   catch (\Throwable $th) {
    //throw $th;

    var_dump($th);
    return [];
}
```

siempre que tienes un metodo con un tipado estricto y tiene que retornar algo debes hacerlo desde dentro de todas las ramas que se generan sea `if`/`else`/`try-catch`

Ejemplo:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

class FooClass
{
    public static function fooMethod(): array
    {
        try
        {
            
            $datos = [];
            $datos[] = 'Hello World!';

            self::$datos();

            return $datos;
            
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return [];
        }
    }
}

$test = new FooClass();
$result = $test::fooMethod();

var_dump($result);
```

en `php 8.1` puedes utilizar varios tipos como dato de retorno:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

class FooClass
{
    public static function fooMethod(): null|array
    {
        try
        {
            
            $datos = [];
            $datos[] = 'Hello World!';

            self::$datos();

            return $datos;
            
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return null;
        }
    }
}

$test = new FooClass();
$result = $test::fooMethod();

var_dump($result);
```

incluso puede retornar el objeto del catch (`Exception`):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

class FooClass
{
    public static function fooMethod(): Exception|array
    {
        try
        {
            
            $datos = [];
            $datos[] = 'Hello World!';

            self::$datos();

            return $datos;
            
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            return $e;
        }
    }
}

$test = new FooClass();
$result = $test::fooMethod();

var_dump($result);
```